Parsing _embedded items from HAL with Quarkus REST client
For Quarkus REST extension I can use quarkus-rest-links extension to support HAL format. There are two handy annotation to inject links @RestLink(rel = "list"), @InjectRestLinks.
I'm trying to parse HAL body with REST Client.
{
    "_embedded": {
        "entity": [
....
}

Is there is any extension or mechanism to support that? I know that I can wrap it in response object line response._embedded.entity1 but I would like some more generic mechanism.
